# Aggregation function in Objection.js

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

How I can write query with Objection.js?

```
SELECT AVG(field), COUNT(*) FROM tab
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const result = await Tab.query().avg(`field`).count(`*`)
console.log(result[0].avg, result[0].count)
```

Comment: Hello, I see you are new to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation when answering a question rather than just pasting the code without explanation :)

Comment: @crodev sorry for my ignorance, I thought the code itself is quite expressive, `avg()` and `count()` are built in methods provided by the library. Official doc: [https://knexjs.org/](https://knexjs.org/)